# Implementing extra field in core data as the iPhone Contacts app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Basically i need to implement the same extra field mecanism as in the iPhone contact app? I was wondering how to model/implement those custom extra fields in core data. Is there a pattern i could follow to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to create an entity that models a generic field then put as many as needed in a to-many relationship with whatever entity your displaying in the table.